# K6 Script sending a request to the backend APIs but the parameter is empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, stress-testing, k6

i have a k6 script that reads two images and send them to a .net core API, the script is:

```
import http from "k6/http";

const path = "path/image1";
const path2 = "path/image2";

const image1Byte = open(path, "b");
const image2Byte = open(path2, "b");
const image1Name = "image1.jpeg";
const image2Name = "image2.jpeg";


export default function () {
  try {
    console.log("Start");
    sendFiles();
    console.log("Finish");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function sendFiles() {
  const url = "path/to/server";
  const image1 = http.file(image1Byte , image1Name );
  const image2 = http.file(image2Byte , image2Name );
  const files = [];
  files.push(image1);
  files.push(image2);
  let response = http.post(url,{files});
  return response;
}
```

the API that receives the request is:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostFiles")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Dictionary<string, long>>> PostFiles([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
```

in the above case the request is caught at the api, but `files` at the API is always has count of 0, although if i send only one image to the API such as:

```
const files = image1
```

it reaches the API correct and i can read its data of the image1,
what I'm doing wrong here?
keep in mind that in both cases the request reaches the API but in list case the parameter `files` is empty

Comment: You can use `F12` to see the value of  `const files = [];` . What's the result ?

Comment: [{"data":[255,....etc],"filename":"image1.jpeg","content_type":"application/octet-stream"},{"data":[255,217....etc],"filename":"image2","content_type":"application/octet-stream"}] 
this is the value of it, as you can see its a correct array
Note: the byte array  "data" value is too long i kept only one bite for ease of read